# Can I use PayPal for non-US iTunes Store payments?

Tags: itunes-store, paypal

Can I use PayPal for non-US iTunes Store payments?

I've heard US users can do so, but my PayPal and iTunes account are non-US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payment methods vary greatly among the many iTunes stores around the world and are often fit to the local market. In Germany, for example, it's possible to pay via direct-debit, because this is a very common way to pay there. There are iTunes stores (additionally to the US one) which accept PayPal - UK comes to mind. In your case I would check my iTunes account to see whether it is possible to pay via PayPal.

Comment: thanks! actually, I've found that debit cards are accepted in my local store, so there is no need of paypal for me

Answer (score 0):

One way to pay in foreign stores is to buy gift vouchers (i.e. on ebay) and open a second account with a fake address and use these vouchers.